# git is unrecongised even I have installed it on my machine

Tags: android, git

In this [tutorial](http://www.tutorialsbuzz.com/2014/11/android-volley-library-build-project.html) they said:

> To Clone volley you need to install Git GUI Client from (
>   http://git-scm.com/download ), I have installed Git GUI Client on my
>   windows machine After Installing Set the environment variable . After
>   Installing Git type the following below command line in your command
>   prompt.

```
 git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley
```

I have installed the gui git , and when I run the command I get git is unreconginised.

if I go to gui and and push to https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley they asked for username and password.

all I want is to clone volley and start using in my app. how to do that ?

Comment: Did you actually install git? Or did you just install the GUI? Also what OS are you running? Keep in mind, if you are on Windows, your CLI won't recognize git I believe unless you set it in your environment path. I believe for windows they have an application (git bash) you download which gives you a terminal that lets you run git commands.

Comment: @aug I have installed GUI git , with interface , I am running windows do you know what is the name of the terminal to download it ?

Comment: Why are you running it from the command line if you want to use the GUI version?

Comment: @MatthewRead they said to run it for cmd , how to run it then in gui version,? I tried to 'commit' but it didnt work , I tried push but asked for username and pass

Comment: Please check this link. https://windows.github.com/ I think its solve your problem.

Comment: I was following this link http://guides.beanstalkapp.com/version-control/git-on-windows.html .. but I had to install beanstall and I dunno what else,  to make it run , I mean isnt there a simple way to clone volley ? should I instal several things in order to clone it ?

Comment: But I am use this and work properly .. please check and install again..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing the git GUI vs installing git on the command line are different things.

When you download git, it should come with an application called git bash that looks like this

[image]

For Windows, you have to open this application which will come out with a terminal window of its own where you can perform git commands.

Keep in mind it has some basic things similar for navigation like in Linux (you can still use `cd` to navigate and wherever you do `git clone`, it will make the repo in that folder.

If you want to run git commands from command prompt, you need to check the option while installing i.e.

[image]

You can check if it's working on Command Prompt by typing `git` and you should see options come up.

Comment: yes I did run git bush that its similar to cmd and I was able to clone it . and I got a new folder called volley. but I know its another question but how to add this new folder to my android project so I can use it ?

Comment: I tired project --> propeties --. android .. --> add .. but I couldnt find volley

Comment: As you may have guessed, you would need to create another question for that but honestly [I would try doing some research yourself](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/training/volley/index.html). As stated in Step 2 you have to import the project into your Android library project. They attached a [link of where to look for that info as well](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html).